# How to Make a Parallel Structure when a Same-Class word is Not Found?

Tags: adjectives, parallelism

I want to make a sentence, adequately using parallel structures, and can't find a way for that. I couldn't find an adjective for tobacco-relative, like I have for alcohol and automotive, in the following list:

> tobacco, alcoholic and automotive goods

In a way I could write a phrase:

> The new tax applies to tobacco, alcoholic and automotive goods.

Is there any way to make sentences like this parallel?

*Edited: I think the way I framed the question people would understand it as three different nouns; when I was actually meaning three different adjectives for goods. This is why I have provided an example phrase.

Comment: I would make the first two agree, and not worry too much about the last item, since it is separated from the others by a conjunction: "I sell tobacco, alcohol and automotive goods." It's not perfect but it's passable.

Comment: I agree with @Mick. Plus, "alcoholic goods" is a bad phrase given that "alcoholic" has the primary sense of "someone addicted to alcohol."

Comment: @Mick Nothing wrong with the parallelism you suggest. Three noun phrases. There is no count/non-count issue.

Comment: @Mick I don't think he sells tobacco and alcohol, he sells tobacco-related products and alcohol-related products.

Comment: @Barmar I think you're wrong. 'tobacco: ... 3. Products made from these plants.' {[AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tobacco)}. Likewise, the third sense AHD lists for 'alcohol'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm referring to what the OP is trying to say. He wants a word that parallels "automotive" in the phrase "automotive goods", but applies to tobacco-related products.

Comment: 'Tobacco' adequately parallels say 'sweets', 'drapery', 'grocery', 'alcohol', 'automotive goods', 'newspapers', 'stationery' ...

Comment: The grammatical problem would disappear if you changed "goods" to "products" because "tobacco" commonly functions as an adjective in that context.  "Tobacco products" is common, whereas "tobacco goods" is not.  (Of course you have to decide, on the basis of the tax law you're summarizing, whether "products" accurately conveys your intent.)

Comment: Looks like I didn't answer you guys (as I thought I did). My apologies!
I think @Barmar got my point, it's tobacco-related, alcohol-related and automobile-related goods in this case.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, I like your idea, I couldn't use it though, as it was a translation required to be written "precisely equal", and my friend thought it was a bad idea changing it to products. Thus we did it by changing the order: we used "alcoholic, automotive and tobacco-related goods", and I hope her readers get that LOL

Answer (score 2):

I can see that you're looking for brevity, but it can compromise understanding or accuracy, so I suggest the following:

The new tax applies to goods in the following classes: tobacco, alcoholic, and automotive.

If the word 'classes' is not suitable for the circumstances you're referring to maybe 'groups' would be better. Regardless, by specifying that you are referring to classes/groups you make it clear that you are not literally referring to raw tobacco.

Comment: I apologize for the late feedback. I voted it up, as it would normally answer such question and I think it's really a good answer. I couldn't use it, though, as it was a translation, thus I had to sticky to the original phrase. Thanks anyway, @user69911 :D